# Solving a piecewise function for a given intercept in Matlab

Tags: matlab, piecewise

I'm trying to solve a piecewise function, but I am getting an error. The following is the code.

---

script:

```
syms x
y_intercept = 2;
answerr = solve(pw_f(x) == y_intercept, x);
```

---

piecewise function (in a separate file within the same folder):

```
function y = pw_f(x)

if x < 0
    y = x;
elseif (x >=0) && (x <= 20)
    y = 2*x;
elseif x > 20
    y = 4*x - 40;
else
end

end
```

---

The error I'm getting after running the script is:

```
Conversion to logical from sym is not possible.

Error in pw_f (line 3)
if x < 0

Error in solve_test
answerr = fsolve(pw_f(x) == y_intercept, x);
```

---

I know that the error is because Matlab can't perform the comparison x < 0 because x is a symbolic variable, so it does not know what x is yet. I also tried using fsolve, and vpasolve but I'm still getting the same error. Do you know how to solve this in Matlab or get around this error?

Of course, this is an easy problem that I can do in my head (x = 1 is the solution) so Matlab should be able to do this!! However, I want to make this generic for any y-intercept (maybe some random number that is not such a nice whole number) that I choose. PLEASE HELP!!!! Thanks :)

FYI, I am using Matlab R2013a.

Comment: have you tried using [fzero()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) or [fminsearch()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## In file called `pw_f.m`

```
function y = pw_f(x)

if x < 0
    y = x;
elseif (x >=0) && (x <= 20)
    y = 2*x;
elseif x > 20
    y = 4*x - 40;
else
end

end
```

## In command window

```
>> y_intercept = 2; % set object value
>> x0 = 0;          % initial guess
>> answerr = fzero(@(x)pw_f(x) - y_intercept, x0) % solve

answerr =

     1

>> pw_f(answerr)  % test solution

ans =

     2
```